# Wordpress join posts with meta values of array type

Tags: post-meta

How do I get all the posts matching meta value of type array

```
function author_posts_join_filter($join){
    global $wpdb,$wp_query;
    $meta_name_author = '_authors';
    if(is_author()){
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id "
               . "AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$meta_name_co_author' "
               . "AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '" . $wp_query->query_vars['author'] . "' "; //this condition removes need for DISTINCT
    }
    return $join;
}
}

add_filter('posts_join', 'author_posts_join_filter');
```

it does not returns all the posts which are co_authored.
I am storing the co_authors as an array in the meta field '_authors'.

Comment: [PHP/MYSQL using an array in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Comment: Is the `meta_value` a PHP serialized array? That is, does the data in the database look something like this? `a:3:{i:0;i:123;i:1;i:456;i:2;i:789;}`

Comment: yes it is serialized